# Access VBA SendObject error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following VBA Access code which is working fine except for the fact that when the user decided to close the Outlook window and decided not to send the email the Access interface freezes:

```
Dim strSubject As String
strSubject = "Receipt number: " & [Reports]![RCPT_MAIN_EMAIL].[RECEIPT]

 Dim strBody As String
strBody = "Dear Sir/Madam," & vbCrLf
strBody = strBody & "Attached Receipt number " & [Reports]![RCPT_MAIN_EMAIL].[RECEIPT] & " for your payment." & vbCrLf


  DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "RCPT_MAIN_EMAIL", acFormatPDF, [Reports]![RCPT_MAIN_EMAIL].[Email], "123@test.com", "", strSubject, strBody, True, ""
'DoCmd.Close acReport, "RCPT_MAIN_EMAIL", acSaveNo


send_res_email_Exit:
DoCmd.Close acReport, "RCPT_MAIN_EMAIL", acSaveNo
    Exit Function

send_res_email_Err:

    MsgBox Error$
    Resume send_res_email_Exit


End Function
```

This basically opens a hidden form, reads the EMAIL value and sends the email via Outlook. But if the user decide to close the outlook message window it gives a message saying that The SendObject was cancelled and freezes.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, I would simply add a

```
On Error Resume Next
```

before the `DoCmd.SendObject` line.

If you need to take action when the message is not sent, do

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.SendObject acReport ...
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' User has canceled
End If
```